# Udacity Fundamental of programming with Python:

Tags: python

```
import urllib.request

def read_text():
        quotes = open(r"C:\Users\Intel\Google Drive\Udacity\Full Stack\AbdoulCoverLetter.txt")
        contents_of_files = quotes.read()
        print(contents_of_files)
        quotes.close()
        check_profanity(contents_of_files)
```

My code is showing the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2022' in position 154: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am not sure what is the issue. Please help..

```
def check_profanity(text_to_check):
    with urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q="+text_to_check) as response:
        connection = response.read()
    output = connection.read()
    connection.close()
read_text()
```

Comment: import urllib.request

def read_text():
        quotes = open(r"C:\Users\Intel\Google Drive\Udacity\Full Stack\AbdoulCoverLetter.txt")
        contents_of_files = quotes.read()
        print(contents_of_files)
        quotes.close()
        check_profanity(contents_of_files)
        

def check_profanity(text_to_check):
    with urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q="+text_to_check) as response:
        connection = response.read()
    output = connection.read()
    connection.close()
read_text()

Comment: Your API response contains some non-ascii characters, you need to encode the response to `utf-8`

Comment: Is the document "AbdoulCoverLetter.txt" written with an ASCII character set?  If not, you have to set the proper encoding in the `open` function.

Comment: "AbdoulCoverLetter" is just a notepad cover letter with alphabetical character and numbers. I added .encode('utf-9') to the line below and it still doesn't work. I am not sure if I didn't right.

Comment: with urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q="+text_to_check).encode('utf-8') as response:

Comment: \u2022 is the bullet symbol.  Does your file have a bulleted list in it?

Comment: Yes. I have bullet list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the bullet list and I changed the code. It is working fine now. Thanks..

```
import urllib.request

def read_text():
        quotes = open(r"C:\Users\Intel\Google Drive\Udacity\Full Stack\AbdoulCoverLetter.txt")
        contents_of_files = quotes.read()
        print(contents_of_files)
        quotes.close()
        check_profanity(contents_of_files)


def check_profanity(text_to_check):
    connection = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?" + urllib.parse.urlencode([('q', text_to_check)]))
    output = connection.read()
    connection.close()
read_text()
```

Comment: Ideally, you should still use `with` statement

Comment: FYI I think if you put encoding='utf-8' in your `open` function call, it would read the file even with the bullet list.  But if you have it working you probably don't want to mess with it.